# UIView animation not working properly

Tags: ios, animation, subview

I'm having some problems with UIView subview animations. What I'm trying to do is that when you press the main view, a subview will slide down from the top and on the next tap it will slide up and be removed. But in the current state, it just does the first tap commands and on the second tap, it displays a nslog, but the removal of the view and the animation doesn't work.

Here is the code in the event handling function:

```
- (void)tapGestureHandler: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
NSLog(@"tap");

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -41.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);
UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"]];
topBar.backgroundColor = background;

if (topBarState == 0) {
     [self.view addSubview:topBar];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{topBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);}];
    topBarState = 1;
} else if (topBarState == 1){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{topBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -41.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);} completion:^(BOOL finished){[topBar removeFromSuperview];}];

    NSLog(@"removed");
    topBarState = 0;
}

}
```

How do i make it so that the subview animate and is removed properly?

Best Regards

FreeSirenety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are always set the topBar frame with y = -41, so for topBarState = 1, animation works for `y=-41 to y=-41` and seems to be as not working

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -41.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);
UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

every time you are creating the view topBar.
Declare topBar in .h and alloc init in viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -41.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);
    topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"]];
    topBar.backgroundColor = background;
        [self.view addSubview:topBar];
    topBarState = 0;
}

- (void)tapGestureHandler: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (topBarState == 0) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{topBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);}];
            topBarState = 1;
    } else if (topBarState == 1){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{topBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -41.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 41.0f);} completion:^(BOOL finished){[topBar removeFromSuperview];}];
        topBarState = 0;
    }
}
```